# Нужен таймер обратного отсчета на js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, laravel

Сюда обратился, потому что в гугле не нашел толкового ответа. Там при запросе таймер js, черт ногу сломит! 
В общем, помогите найти или поделитесь своим таймером.
Нужен таймер на JS, чтобы время задавалось в ручную: 30 минут, 1 день, 1 неделя и 1 месяц. (Таймер не должен начинаться заново после обновления страницы).
После того как время вышло, нужно с помощью ajax отправить post запрос на указанный роут (laravel) что таймер закончился.

Comment: Вот вам аналогичные [вопрос/ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD*)

Comment: Я бы сделал это с помощью `cookie`. Если вкратце: берете любой плагин плагин, например, `jQuery Simple Timer`. Проверяете куки. Если значения в куки нет, запускаете таймер с коллбэком `onComplete:`, в котором прописываете свой `ajax запрос`, и создаете куки

Answer (score 2):

Есть множество плагинов для обратного отсчёта для jQuery. Например https://github.com/kbwood/countdown позволяет делать обратный отсчёт в любых форматах - [есть множество примеров](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) .

Cамый популярный плагин обратного отсчёта - этот http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ - также [примеров множество](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples.html).

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#countdown-example').countdown({
    until: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1),
    onExpiry: function(){ alert('Ура, новый год!!!'); /*Тут ваш POST запрос*/ },
    padZeroes: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/countdown/master/dist/js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/countdown/master/dist/js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/countdown/master/dist/css/jquery.countdown.css">

<H2>Новый год скоро!</H2>
<span id="countdown-example"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю можно сделать так. В сервере при загрузке страницы задать вот такой параметр `js` `let session_timer = '<?php echo $_SESSION["session_timer"]; ?>';`.

Когда все в первый раз в сервере задаем например `<?php $_SESSION["session_timer"] = false; ?>`.

```js
if(!session_timer){
  let ajax_timer = 30*60;
  //(пример 30минут) здесь расчет времени

  let session_timer = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + ajax_timer;
  //в это время должен происходить `ajax` запрос.
  
  send_ajax_timer_to_server();
  
}

function send_ajax_timer_to_server(){
    //здесь другой ajax запросом вы должны отправить таймер в сервер и там сахранить его в сессии.
}
```

Потом в фронте когда задаешь время (30м, 1д и т.д.) если `session_timer` ровно `false`. Потом когда задали время или таймер из сессии уже установлен уже можно написать логику к примеру вот так.

Допустим мы задали время 30 минут и потом закрыли страницу, а потом открыли к примеру после 10 минут, сейчас мы должны рассчитать сколько времени прошло с момента установки времени.

```js
let timeout_timer = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) - session_timer;

if(timeout_timer > 0){
  setTimeout(ajax_timer_func, timeout_timer*1000);
}
else{
  //когда открыли страницу позже то сразу запускаем функцию для ajax запроса
  ajax_timer_func();
}

function ajax_timer_func(){
  //здесь код вашего ajax запроса
}
```

Я бы сделал так, если есть недостатки можете написать в комментариях.